# Send notification (firebase functions) to specific uid after a database update

Tags: android, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an angular ionic app that exchange data (animal data) between users, I'm using firebase real time database and users can share their data between them
In my firebase database I have a Node of Users, each have its uid and each uid have a list of animals
Users->{uid}->animalList->cat,dog

Now I wanted user 1 to be notified when user 2 shared one of his animal with him
So after a new animal is added to a user node he will be notified of that

I read i need to add fcm but i got lost
I wanted it to happen in this function (but maybe its not the right way)

```
exports.updatedUserNode = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
cors(req, res, async () => {
if (req.method !== 'POST') {
  return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Not allowed.' });
}

const { email, objectData } = req.body;

if (!email || !objectData) {
  return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid data.' });
}

try {
  const user = await fbAdmin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);
  const uid = user.uid;

  await fbAdmin.database().ref(`/Users/${uid}/PersonsList`).push(objectData);

  //here it sends a notification on the uid phone 
  

  return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Object added successfully.' });
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred.' });
}
});
});
```

I'm not using firestore
I tried the ionic docs it didn't help
I'm using angular/ionic

Thanks very much!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to notify users when something interesting happens, so I recommend readigng the documentaiton for that use-case: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens